# How to convert an InMemoryUploadedFile in django to a fomat for flickr API?

Tags: python, django, flickr

I have a class that uploads a file to Flickr. The file is of type
'InMemoryUploadedFile'.

I would like to know how to convert or pass the data in the 'InMemoryUploadedFile' file, to a format for flickr's API?

Eg:

```
{'photo': ('image.jpg', <InMemoryUploadedFile: image.jpg (image/jpeg)>)}
```

Upload API: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

**Error Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="fail">
    <err code="4" msg="Filesize was zero" />
</rsp>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`InMemoryUploadedFile` is a [wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile) around a file object. You can access the file object using the `file` attribute. So, in your example, try passing this to the Flickr API:

```
{'photo': my_in_memory_file.file}
```

If that doesn't work, please edit your question with more detail around the code you're using to submit the request.

Comment: Thanks. But it returns: {'photo': ('image.jpg', <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10dbefa70>)}

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="fail">
 <err code="4" msg="Filesize was zero" />
</rsp>

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using? Both the code that outputs `{'photo': ('image.jpg', <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10dbefa70>)}` and the code you're using to post the photo to the API.

Answer (score 3):

The data inside the InMemoryUploadedFile onbject was extracted and passed to Flickr succesfully via:

```
import StringIO
file.seek(0)
file_handle = StringIO.StringIO(file.read())
{'photo': ('image.jpg', file_handle)}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not valid for python 3.

Comment: I would be careful with this. You'll probably want to read in chunks instead. Note the warning in the official Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.read