# How to convert an image (get from request.FILES) to byte array in python?

Tags: python, file, io

Suppose I have a variable "profile_image" of image file type. I have created the variable like below:

```
profile_image = request.FILES.get('profile_image', False)
```

Now I need to convert this image variable to bytes array. How can I do this without saving it to the local drive?
I found that file open/read do not work here. I tried like below:

```
with open(profile_image.name, "rb") as imageFile:
       file_stream = imageFile.read()
```

Please help me. By the way, by converting into bytes array I want to save it to google cloud.

Thank you.

Comment: try bytearray(profile_image)

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351254/python-script-to-convert-image-into-byte-array/22351973?

Comment: @ChandanKumar bytearray() is not useful.

Comment: @GauravPaliwal thanks. I checked that, but could not find the silution that I need.

Answer (score 5):

After googling for a long time I found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417049/how-to-convert-an-inmemoryuploadedfile-in-django-to-a-fomat-for-flickr-api).

Actually "profile_image" is an "InMemoryUploadedFile" object in python. We can read the file like below:

```
profile_image.file.read()
```

Comment: If I do that, I get `b''`, even though I do have the correct `InMemoryUploadedFile` from Django.